# Passing multiple tuples with default parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing

I realize this might be a somewhat strange request, but I'd like to have a method accept an arbitrary amount of tuples in Python 3, each tuple with default parameters.

The reason I'd like to do this is because I'm writing scripting functionality for our group, and want callable methods for users to be easy to understand. For example, if the user wants to call a 2D plotting method, I want the method arguments to look like this:

```
plot2D(('sweepvar1', start1, stop1, npts1=None, step1=None),
       ('sweepvar2', start2, stop2, npts2=None, step2=None))
```

So the user calls something like this

```
plot2D(('var1', 0.0, 1.0, npts1=101), ('var2', 0.5, 0.6, step2=0.001))
```

Essentially the difficulty is coming because I don't know apriori if the user wants to specify a number of points or a step size for the measurement, but we need to include both options. Ideally I want to avoid forcing users to specify both, or create a new variable that is a flag for choosing between `npts` and `step`.

I am somewhat familiar with `default parameters`, `*args`, and `**kwargs`, but I can't seem to come up with a clean solution to the above problem.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Well these are not tuples, since these contained named parameters...

Comment: looks more like namedtuples.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using custom objects rather than tuples, so that everything can be initialized properly by the user.

Comment: I know it sounds petty, and maybe there is no better way to do it, but I was hoping to find a solution that doesn't involve something like

    `plot2D(CustomObject('var1', 0.0, 1.0, npts=101), CustomObject('var2', 0.0, 1.0, step=0.01))`

Comment: @spaderdabomb I have provided 2 alternatives. Of course none of them fits exactly your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems difficult to achieve as-is, *but* you could create an helper function which wraps the arguments and creates a tuple of positional & keyword args for each tuple. Call that `mkarg` (make argument)

```
def mka(*args,**kwargs):
    return (args,kwargs)

def plot2D(t1,t2):
    print(t1,t2)

plot2D(mka('var1', 0.0, 1.0, npts1=101), mka('var2', 0.5, 0.6, step2=0.001))
```

this test returns:

```
(('var1', 0.0, 1.0), {'npts1': 101}) (('var2', 0.5, 0.6), {'step2': 0.001})
```

now the tedious work is to process those arguments in `plot2D`, but at least users have a clear interface.

**Alternative:**

if you *really* want tuples, you could check the `len` of your tuple parameters, and complete with `None` if not long enough. That's good if the second "optional" value is less used than the first. Practical for a small amount of "optional" values.

```
def plot2D(tuple1,tuple2):
    tuple1 += (None,)*(5-len(tuple1))
    tuple2 += (None,)*(5-len(tuple2))

plot2D(('var1', 0.0, 1.0, 101), ('var2', 0.5, 0.6, None, 0.001))
```

Comment: Oh nice I really like the alternative! Kinda crazy I didn't even consider that. I think forcing the user to specify `None` does not create that much overhead in reality, so that sounds like it will work well to me.

Comment: fun part: this was my first answer, but I deleted it (because I thought that the passing by keyword was more important for you)